How to get AudioKit Playgrounds Swift playground book to work
I've tried following the instructions at https://github.com/AudioKit/Playgrounds/tree/master and downloaded the .zip and put it in my Playgrounds directory.
It unzips fine and I can open up AudioKit in Playgrounds, but there are errors all over the place, e.g. 'Cannot find AKAudioPlayer in scope'. There are lots of others where it can't find classes beginning 'AK..'
When I look at the AudioKit documentation https://www.audiokit.io/AudioKit/documentation/audiokit, there are no classes beginning 'AK..'. Is this playground book maybe out of date with more recent changes to AudioKit?
Also although it imports AVFoundation at the top of the first page, it doesn't import AudioKit itself anywhere. I can kind of fix things by adding imports and using AVAudioFile instead of AKAudioFile, but I don't know if I've just got something fundamentally wrong with the config.
Any pointers gratefully received, thanks.

Yes, these Playgrounds have been deprecated. Use Cookbook instead: https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook
Cookbook is Xcode project and you’d need a Mac.

Thanks for your reply. I've tried to import cookbook but found out I can't since it's a project not a package (I'm very new to this sort of programming). I'm only using an iPad, no Mac and beginning to think I'm wasting my time, but would love to be corrected.
